# getting backend flash messages from SPA frontend

Tags: angularjs, pyramid, single-page-application, flash-message, ngboilerplate

I found it is very hard to deal with flash message returned from backend when working with single-page-application.

Say there are five actions:

login, logout,search,add,delete.

each action emits messages(successful or failed,could be more). in a Non-SPA, it is easy enough to do something like  **backend.getFlash()** in the template to get the message stored in session.

However, in SPA, if the results are returned in JSON, and of course backend can pass the message to a js framework, say angularjs. But it is really tedious and not flexible at all.

Does anyone have any idea or experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From your question I understood that what you really want is to have some messages for every actions, say for delete you need to display a message like "Deleted Successfully" and you don't want this message to be send along with the result set from your backend.

In AngularJS you can achieve this by having a `service` for showing the messages.

Here is an example;

Create a service like this in AngularJS

```
app.factory('FlashService', function ($rootScope) {

    return {
        show: function (message) {
            $rootScope.flash = message;
            return message;
        },
        clear: function () {
            $rootScope.flash = '';
            return null;
        }
    };
});
```

Here **FlashService** is the name of the service you are creating, don't bother about the name you can give any name of your choice.

To use this service inject it anywhere you want like;

```
var app = angular.module("your app name", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function(FlashService) { 
   FlashService.show("I am here");
});
```

And use it in your html like

```
<div id="flash">{{flash}}</div>
```